# Drupal along side Magento on Nginx

Tags: php, magento2, php-7, nginx-location

I have successfully setup Magento 2.0 and trying to install Drupal along side. My Nginx configurations:

```
    upstream fastcgi_backend {
        server unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name www.my-server.com;
        set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/magento;
        set $MAGE_MODE default;
        include /var/www/magento/nginx.conf.sample;
        location /drupal/ {
            root /var/www/html;
            fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }
    }
```

I have also added a sample `index.php` to `/var/www/html`.

Executing `curl http://www.my-server.com/drupal/` gives `File not found.`

How can I add a Drupal installation alongside Magento?

## More details

### Nginx error log

```
*3 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: www.my-server.com, request: "GET /drupal/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "www.my-server.com"
```

### Magento Nginx configuration

[nginx.conf.sample](https://github.com/emizentech/magento2/blob/master/nginx.conf.sample)

### HTTP headers

```
curl -I http://www.my-server.com/drupal/
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: nginx/1.8.1
Date: Wed, 20 Apr 2016 06:12:08 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: keep-alive
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm new to Nginx and Drupal, I was not able to get both served under different locations.

My workaround was using 2 different domains as Nginx supports multiple servers:

```
server {
    server_name www.my-server.io;
    ...
}

server {
    server_name www.my-drupal-server.io;
    ...
}
```